# "Cannot set property 'length' of undefined " error when querying my mySQL using NodeJs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Im trying to query mySQL database using NodeJS to check if a row exists if it doesn't to create it if it does to update it however am getting an error of 'Cannot set property 'length' of undefined' not sure why kindly assist. Below is my code

```
const latitude = req.body.latitude;
const longitude = req.body.longitude;
const user_email = req.body.user_email;

  db.query('SELECT * FROM location WHERE user_email =?', [user_email], 
  (error, results, fields)=>{
    if (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      res.send("success");
    } else if(results && results.length == 0){
      db.query('INSERT INTO location(latitude, longitude, user_email) VALUES("'+latitude+'", "'+longitude+'", "'+user_email+'")',
                   [latitude, longitude, user_email]);
      res.send("success");
    }else{
      db.query('UPDATE location SET latitude = ? , longitude = ?, WHERE user_email = ? '[latitude, longitude,user_email]);
      res.send("success");
    }
  }
```

)

Comment: The error message means that your "results" variable is "undefined".

Comment: @paulsm4 how do i make it return a variable that is defined

Comment: console.log the results after the if statement and see what it is returning before doing the else if

Comment: Your `results` isn't undefined.... because you say `results && results.length` which means it is definitely not undefined. Is that the line where the error is occurring?

Comment: @Diesel the error occurs at the UPDATE query

Comment: @Tosh Gitonga - thank you for modifying the code like I suggested.  Now *PLEASE UPDATE THE ERROR MESSAGE*.  Because I imagine it's no longer "Cannot set property 'length' of undefined ”.  Please include the line# the error is occurring.  You can use Chrome Developer Tools, if you're not already familiar with it: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: @Tosh Gitonga: Q: have you resolved the problem?  If not, please update your post with the current code, and the current error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested changes:

```
  db.query(
   'SELECT * FROM location WHERE user_email =?',[user_email],  
   (error, results, fields)=>{
     if (error) {
       console.error(error.message);
       res.send("success");
     } else if (results && results.length == 0){
       db.query(
          'INSERT INTO location(latitude, longitude, user_email)
        VALUES("'+latitude+'", "'+longitude+'", "'+user_email+'")',
          [latitude, longitude, user_email]);
      res.send("success");
    }else{
    ...
```

Notes:

1. Check for errors.  Always check for errors :)
2. I believe there should be a comma before [user_mail]
3. Check if "results" null before attempting to reference results.length
4. In Javascript, "==" means "check for equality", whereas "=" means "assign to variable".

Comment: i am still getting the same error, kindly take a look at the updated snippet

Comment: @Tosh Gitonga - I don't see how you could possibly be getting "the same error" ("'Cannot set property 'length' of undefined' ) ... after you made the changes, and if ..."the error occurs at the UPDATE query".  Please update your post with *THE EXACT, CURRENT ERROR MESSAGE*.  Please identify the line#.  Please use [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/) (if it would help).

Answer (score 0):

One option here would be to take advantage of MySQL's `ON DUPLICATE KEY` functionality.  Assuming your had a unique index on the `user_email` column, you may try this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO location (latitude, longitude, user_email)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE latitude = ?, longitude = ?;
```

This would only require a single query in Node:

```
db.query('INSERT INTO location (latitude, longitude, user_email) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE latitude = ?, longitude = ?',
    [latitude, longitude, user_email, latitude, longitude]);
res.send("success");
```

The major potential problem with doing a select first, and basing the decision on whether or not to insert on that select, is that another process might insert in between these two commands.  That is, unless you use a certain type of transaction to ensure that the select and update happen atomically, your code's current approach could still result in a duplicate record being inserted.  Using `ON DUPLICATE KEY` places this responsibility on the database.

Comment: I'll abide by insults but not by false accusations, such as [the one that you recently made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57764291/how-to-print-a-specific-digit-of-an-integer#comment101964341_57764312). You don't know who down-voted you, nor do I. All I know is that it was not me. Please do keep this in mind in the future before making such accusations.

Comment: However my primary keys are auto increment and can never be duplicate it is the foreign key that i don't want to be duplicate, the user_email

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: actually I do use botox (if you're truly interested). We have injected it into the base of the esophagus for patients with an extremely severe form of esophageal spasm called "achalasia", relieving the spasm and allowing them to eat.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen - nothing to do with your suggestion ... but I'd really like to know if the OP is still experiencing the original error and, if not 1) exactly what he's changed, and 2) exactly what his current error message says.